# Is there any difference between message.writeto() and message.getinputstream in java mail API?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am trying to write email message to `.eml` file using Java Api.After writing the file I need to validate that the file has been downloaded successfully or not, using '`SHA1`' algorithm .I tried the following.

1)I have written the email message to .eml file, and after completion of downloading ,I have taken the input stream of same mail using `message.getInpuStream()` .Now I used this stream and written `.eml` file's stream to validate. Now it is getting failed.

2)I have written `.eml` by just copying the `InputStream` taken by using `message.getInpuStream()` to some `.eml's` `FileOutputStream`. Again I passed the input stream of these both to validate using `SHA1`. Now validation is successfull but when I open that downloaded .eml file ,its just showing the body content ,not showing any attachments and sender and receiver information.

So I want to know is there any difference between writing the mail message to `.eml` using `message.writeTo()` and using `message.getInputStream`?

Any suggestion or Information is appreciated.

Following is the code I am trying.

```
public class EmailArchiveTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {


        String host = "pop.gmail.com";
        String username = "xxxx@gmail.com"; 
        String password = "password";
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "pop3s");
        Session session = Session.getInstance(new Properties(), null);
        Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
        store.connect(host, username, password);

         Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
         folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

        Message message[] = folder.getMessages();
        OutputStream out=null;
        InputStream inStream=null;
        File file=null;

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

            inStream=message[i].getInputStream();
            file=new File("E:/MailTest/mail-"+i+".msg");
            out=new FileOutputStream(file);

            IOUtils.copy(inStream, out);

            IOUtils.closeQuietly(inStream);
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(out);

            System.out.println("Validating the File ...!!!");

            InputStream srcInStream=message[i].getInputStream();
            InputStream tgtStream=new FileInputStream(file);
            EmailHelper helper=new EmailHelper();
            //calling method to validate the file
            boolean validate=helper.fileValidation(srcInStream, tgtStream, "SHA1");
            if(validate){
                System.out.println("Validation Successful...!!");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Validation Failed..!!");
            }
            tgtStream.close();
            srcInStream.close();    
            }

        folder.close(false);
        store.close();
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: getInputStream() will take care of content only. writeTo is preferred. Have you faced any issues with writeTo? Please post code with writeTo and outstanding issues

Comment: Hi @sunrise76 ,there is no issue with writeTo() for downloading the mail ,but to validate the downloaded file we need inputstream

Answer (score 3):

The writeTo method includes both the headers and the content.  The getInputStream method returns only the content.  If you need an InputStream that contains both the headers and the content, write it to a file and then read it back in, or use a [PipedInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html) and a thread.

Comment: For an eml File (MimeType message/rfc822), the headers need to be there and just putting getInputStream() to a file is not enough. Two threads are not an option in my application, but ByteArrayOutputStream and then ByteArrayInputStream with the expected load on  the GC safely does the trick. Luckily, most mail server restrict message size to something that can be handled in memory.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the type of stream. getInputSteam retrieves an InputStream, while writeTo places the data in an OutputStream.

source
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html

learn more about iostreams
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/

Comment: Yes I know that,but writeTo() also need InputStream to place into OutputStream right?.What I thought is like writeTo() will directly write that message.getInputStream  to OutputStream. But when after seeing the functionality it is looking different